# Cypress: type combination of keys

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, end-to-end, autotest

I'm trying to write the keyboard shortcut 'ctrl+space'

I tried

```
cy.get('body').type('{ctrl}{space}');
```

But it doesn't work

What do you suggest?

Comment: What error are you getting. Post the screenshot here.

Comment: It says that {space} is not recognized and isn't a part of the available sequences such as: enter, shift, del, alt ect.

Comment: Can you try using `cy.get('body').type('{ctrl} ');`

Comment: Do you know what can i do to write the shortcut ctrl+F1?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `{space}` with `' '` worked for OP.

```
cy.get('body').type('{ctrl} ')
```

Comment: Do u know how can i write the shortcut Ctrl+F1?

Comment: Can you try this. I am not sure this will work `cy.get('body').type('{ctrl}').trigger({'keydown', { key: "F1", code: "F1", which: 112 })`

Comment: No there are any bugs, but i think after i type ctrl it gets released so it's like you type the two keys separately

Comment: Can you try this `cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', {key: "Control", code: "ControlLeft", which: 17}).trigger({'keydown', { key: "F1", code: "F1", which: 112 })`